# dirmngr does not start with proper home directory unless it is restarted

Tags: arch-linux, security, gpg

I am trying to follow these guidelines for gpg best practices: https://help.riseup.net/en/security/message-security/openpgp/best-practices

but I am having trouble with dirmngr, which handles all transmission for gpg 2.1 (2.0?) and greater. Basically, dirmngr is not finding the location of my ssl certs that allow me to connect to an hkps keyserver. I am using ArchLinux too.

Connecting to an hkp server works fine:

```
# with "keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net"
[my-pc]/home/me/.gnupg$ gpg --refresh-keys
  gpg: refreshing 7 keys from hkp://keys.gnupg.net
  gpg: key D7E69871: "asdf asdf <blah@blah.org>" not changed
  gpg: key 17A4CD9C: "asdf asdf <blah@blah.org>" not changed
  gpg: key 9741E8AC: "blah alh <fauno@endefensadelsl.org>" 1 new signature
  gpg: Total number processed: 3
  gpg:              unchanged: 2
  gpg:         new signatures: 1
  gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
  gpg: depth: 0  valid:   2  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 2u
  gpg: next trustdb check due at 2018-03-03

# with "keyserver hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net":
[my-pc]/home/me/.gnupg$ gpg --refresh-keys
  gpg: refreshing 7 keys from hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
  gpg: keyserver refresh failed: General error
```

As shown, I get a strange "General error" message. But dirmngr is running:

```
[my-pc]/home/me$ ps aux | grep dirmng
me    17695  0.0  0.0 311016  7240 ?        Ssl  Dec30   0:01 dirmngr --daemon --homedir /home/me/.gnupg
me    27366  0.0  0.0  10732  2376 pts/41   S+   14:35   0:00 grep --color=auto dirmng
```

And a little debugging shows that my certs aren't being loaded:

```
[my-pc]/home/me$ dirmngr --debug-level guru
  dirmngr[27054.0]: enabled debug flags: x509 crypto memory cache memstat hashing ipc lookup
  dirmngr[27054.0]: permanently loaded certificates: 0
  dirmngr[27054.0]:     runtime cached certificates: 0
  dirmngr[27054.0]: DBG: chan_4 -> # Home: ~/.gnupg
  # Home: ~/.gnupg
  dirmngr[27054.0]: DBG: chan_4 -> # Config: /home/me/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf
  # Config: /home/lucas/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf
  dirmngr[27054.0]: DBG: chan_4 -> OK Dirmngr 2.1.10 at your service
  OK Dirmngr 2.1.10 at your service
```

After reading the docs here: https://www.gnupg.org/%28en%29/documentation/manuals/dirmngr.pdf
it says that the `--homedir` flag only works on the commandline, so I killed and restarted dirmngr, and now `gpg --refresh-keys` seems to work:

```
[my-pc]/home/me$ gpg --refresh-keys
gpg: key 0xD605848ED7E69871: "asdf asdf <blah@blah.org>" not changed
gpg: key 0x456032D717A4CD9C: "asdf asdf <blah@blah.org>" not changed
gpg: key 0x7F2D434B9741E8AC: "asdf asdf <blah@blah.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 3
gpg:              unchanged: 3
```

Does anyone know about this error, and whether there is a fix for it?

**Additional info**
Here is my `~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf`:

```
keyserver hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
hkp-cacert /home/me/.cert/sks-keyservers.netCA.pem
```